# What's the difference between \ref and \autoref?

Tags: cross-referencing

I've always used `\ref` for referring to labelled items, but a LaTeX template I downloaded uses `\autoref` instead. What is the difference?

Comment: Is one of our answers useful to you or do you want more explanations?

Answer (score 96):

`\autoref` is a command from the `hyperref` package which is used to have some automatic prefix added to the reference. For instance if you used `\label{sec:intro}` just after your command for the introduction section the `\autoref{sec:intro}` command will output "section X" with X being the good number.

Of course you can imagine that the prefix depends on the type of the object to which the label is linked. If it is a figure, it will output "figure" and so on.

Note that you can redefine the prefix for the autoref command associated to a given type of object. For instance for the sections use:

```
\def\sectionautorefname{New prefix for the sections}
```

More generally,

```
\def\<type>autorefname{<new name>}
```

Comment: What is the difference between this and `cleveref` ? :)

Comment: One difference is that `cleveref` capitalizes the first letter of the word at the beginning of the sentence, which is pretty useful.

Answer (score 79):

The difference is easy to see in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}\centering
\caption{foo}\label{foo}
\tabular{c}
foo\\\hline
bar\\\hline
\endtabular
\end{table}
\begin{table}\centering
\caption{bar}\label{bar}
\tabular{c}
foo\\\hline
bar\\\hline
\endtabular
\end{table}

See Table~\ref{foo} and 
          \autoref{bar}
\end{document}
```

[image]