# Removing prefix from autoref output

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, autoref

I have started using [`\autoref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) to perform some referencing between sections inside LaTeX.

Consider the following MWE and its screenshot:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}
\label{sec:foo}

Some random text

\section{Bar}
\label{sec:bar}

Some more random text

\section{Baz}
\label{sec:baz}

More random text again \\

I will now reference \autoref{sec:foo},
\autoref{sec:bar}, and \autoref{sec:baz} 

\end{document}
```

The output looks like:

[image: Depiction of the output for the above code]

While reading this it becomes very irritating to read the word `section` repeated multiple times while referencing several sections separated by commas.

Is it possible to generate the last sentence as `I will now reference 1, 2 and 3`, with the hyperlinks to the sections embedded "inside" the numbers as before?. Thus I specifically do not want that `section` prefix before each number in the output.

Comment: You may wish to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/359826) one of the [two](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/436998/134641) [answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/436996/134641).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you rewrite the sentence with one `\autoref` and two `\ref` statements, i.e., as

```
I will now reference \autoref{sec:foo}, \ref{sec:bar}, and \ref{sec:baz}
```

you will get

> I will now reference section 1, 2, and 3

which isn't quite right as the word 'section' appears in singular form.

Instead, I suggest you load the [cleveref](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/) package (after loading `hyperref`) with the option `nameinlink` and use `\cref`, the package's main user-level macro. Importantly, `\cref` can take multiple arguments. If the you write

```
I will now reference \cref{sec:foo,sec:bar,sec:baz}
```

you'll get

> I will now reference sections 1 to 3

with the strings "sections 1" and "3" highlighted as hyperlink targets. (If you don't want the word "sections" to be included in the hyperlink target, don't set the `nameinlink` option.) Note that `\cref` has automatically performed compression of the range of items. If you don't want compression, write

```
I will now reference \cref{sec:foo,,sec:bar,sec:baz}
```

and you'll get

> I will now reference sections 1, 2 and 3

with the strings "sections 1", "2", and "3" acting as hyperlink targets.

---

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image: Rendered output of the above.]

(If you wanted to create a cross-reference of the form "1, 2 and 3" without the "sections" prefix, you could do so by writing `\labelcref{sec:foo,,sec:bar,sec:baz}`.)

The effect of setting the `nameinlink` option is to make the cross-references look like those produced by `\autoref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\begin{document}

\section{Foo} \label{sec:foo}
Some random text
\section{Bar} \label{sec:bar}
Some more random text  
\section{Baz} \label{sec:baz}
More random text again

\bigskip
I will now reference \autoref{sec:foo}, \autoref{sec:bar}, and \autoref{sec:baz}

I will now reference \autoref{sec:foo}, \ref{sec:bar}, and \ref{sec:baz}

I will now reference \cref{sec:foo,,sec:bar,sec:baz}

I will now reference \cref{sec:foo,sec:bar,sec:baz}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish this by simply using [`\ref` instead](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137433/134641).

So `\ref{sec:foo}, \ref{sec:bar}, and \ref{sec:baz}`, produces:

> 1, 2, and 3 [all linked]

Alternatively, you could do `\nameref{sec:foo}, \nameref{sec:bar}, and \nameref{sec:baz}`, to produce:

> Foo, Bar, and Baz [all linked]

You could also combine the above two, to [reference both the section number and name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121871/134641).

Finally, you can change what [`hyperref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) uses for to refer to a `section`:

```
\renewcommand*{\sectionautorefname}{Custom Name}
```

The above would make `\autoref{sec:foo}` yield the following linked text:

> Custom Name 1