# Link to only section and subsection number, without the word "Section"

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, autoref

I would like to add links to the individual section and subsection numbers in my paper. I provided a picture with an example of what I want. So far using `\autoref{}` I get a link that gives "section 3" for example when all I want is the number 3.

Thanks

Comment: Use the `\ref` command.

Answer (score 1):

As @frougon already mentioned in his comment, you can use the `\ref` command to get only the number of a section without the word "section", q.v. [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436994).

There is also [a question which explains the difference of `\ref` and `\autoref`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137432) in detail.