# How to get Proof of Theorem with package phfthm

Tags: theorems

I am trying to use the package `phfthm` to have a proof with the indication *Proof of Theorem 1*, and the like.

I am almost exactly using the example provided in the [package documentation](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/phfthm/phfthm.pdf), at page 15, but I only get *Proof of 1*, without the word *Theorem*, and cannot understand where I am making a mistake.

Here is my example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[resetstyle]{phfthm}

\begin{document}

\section*{Introduction}
This is a theorem
\begin{theorem}[Gauss]
    \label{thm:Gauss}
    For a closed surface $S$ enclosing a volume $V$, we have
    \begin{equation}
    \oint_S\vec u\cdot d\vec S = \int_V(\vec\nabla\cdot\vec u)\,dV\ .
    \end{equation}
\end{theorem}
Then the proof.
\begin{proof}[*thm:Gauss]
text of proof
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to load `hyperref` to provide `\autoref`, which is needed to print the type of proof. If `\autoref` is not available, `\ref` is used as fallback and thus only the number appears (cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137433/29873). This could have been stated more clearly in the documentation (there are only rather hidden remarks). Anyway, here we go:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[resetstyle]{phfthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\section*{Introduction}
This is a theorem
\begin{theorem}[Gauss]
    \label{thm:Gauss}
    For a closed surface $S$ enclosing a volume $V$, we have
    \begin{equation}
    \oint_S\vec u\cdot d\vec S = \int_V(\vec\nabla\cdot\vec u)\,dV\ .
    \end{equation}
\end{theorem}
Then the proof.
\begin{proof}[*thm:Gauss]
text of proof
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]