# Reference authors from \label object

Tags: hyperref

I'm preparing my thesis and its my first time using latex

I have the following file: `paper1.tex`

```
\author
{
    Author 1
    \and
    Author 2
    \and
    Author 3
}
\title{Title of the paper1}
\maketitle
\label{pap:paper1}


\includearticle{papers/papaer1pdf}
```

And I have another file: `ListofPaper.tex`

```
\chapter{List of papers}

\section*{\cref{pap:paper1}}
\enquote{\titleref{pap:paper1}}.
%\enquote{\nameref{pap:paper1}}. % It also works similar as \titleref ¿What is the difference?
```

When i compile it, it shows:

[image]

Is there any way to list the authors before the title of the paper, I mean something like this:

Author 1, Author 2 and Author 3. "Title of the paper"

I was trying with `\autoref{pap:paper1}` but it didn't work.

Comment: (1) I don't know that it is readily possible to retrieve the list of authors from `\author`, at least not in the standard classes. But could you please edit your question to include a **short** compilable example (MWE) starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`? This helps us help you. And there's the chance that the document class you're using provides this possibility.

Comment: (2) Generally, [`\autoref`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137435/) doesn't have anything to do with *"author"*. It is only a `\ref` command that *automatically* generates a descriptive prefix in addition to the number: "section 3.3" instead of just "3.3". In your case, I'd expect it to output something like "Paper 1", not the authors.